# Submitting a PHP upload once files have been selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an image upload script using PHP with a simple multiple file select and then an upload function like below:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("error");
mysql_select_db("repo") or die("error");

$imgerror = '';
if(isset($_POST['log'])){
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $name_tmp){
        $name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $tmpnm = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
        $size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $dir = "content/images/".$name;
        $move = move_uploaded_file($tmpnm,$dir);
        if($move){
            $hsl = mysql_query("insert into files values('','$client','$name','$type','$size',now())");

            if ($hsl){
                $imgerror = "IMAGE(S) UPLOADED SUCCESSFULLY";
            } else {
                $imgerror = "CANNOT CONNECT TO DATABASE";
            }
        } else {
            $imgerror = "NO IMAGES SELECTED";
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="uploadContainer">
    <div><i><?php echo $imgerror ?></i></div>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        <input type="submit" name="log" value="Upload">
    </form>
</div>
```

I did find some information using jQuery from another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686654/is-it-possible-to-upload-image-to-server-without-submitting-the-form) but have no idea how I would implement this into my code, or maybe someone could suggest an alternative. All I am trying to do is select the files, and make it automatically submit without pressing a submit button.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Have a go at it and then ask for help, otherwise this lokks very like a _Do it for me_

Comment: If you don't wait for the submit button, how do you know when the user is finished selecting all the files?

Comment: If you use the `change` event, it will submit as soon as he selects the first file, instead of letting him select multiple.

Comment: No, @Barmar, you can select several files and the form won't submit (in Mozilla Firefox).

Comment: Please read about [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as your code is most likely vulnerable to it. I don't see where `$client` comes from but uploading a file named `');DROP+DATABASE--` would be a problem for your script.

Comment: @migg Why would it be a problem? `mysql_query` won't execute multiple queries. That's a common misunderstanding about SQL-injection.

Comment: @migg Probably caused by the infamous "Little Bobby Tables" story.

Comment: Just because it does not execute multiple queries does not make it safe. You can still do a lot of damage using `UNION SELECT` or stuff like `LOAD_FILE` and `INTO OUTFILE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onchange` event works for inputs type file. Next code auto-submits "once files have been selected" (tested in Mozilla Firefox) :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

function on_change ()
{ alert( "File(s) chosen!" +
         "\n\n" +
         "Click to submit files to upload." );
  document.getElementById( "frm" ).submit();
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="frm" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple onchange="on_change()">
        <input type="submit" name="log" value="Upload">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course, you will have to remove the JavaScript "alert" window, it's there to show that the "onchange" event works.

Comment: How will this know when he's selected **all** the files he wants? Why won't it run `on_change` as soon as he selects the first file, instead of waiting for him to select multiple files?

Comment: @Barmar : create a text file, copy-paste my code, open it with Firefox, click the "browse" button, choose as many files as you want, click the "open" button, and the form will submit.

Comment: I made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/6909ga85/ When I selected the first file, it submitted the form. I never got a chance to select a second file. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: @Barmar, my code works great in your fiddle, using Firefox 45.0.2. What browser are you using?

Comment: I see what's going on. To upload multiple files, you have to select all the files in the same file selector dialog. I thought you could click on the selector multiple times to select files from different folders.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to be working as I have the PHP code in the same file as the HTML code – [like so](http://i.imgur.com/OqHcwLx.png), therefore I am not actually using `action: 'upload.php'` – Any other ideas (thank you for your response though).

Comment: @Xertz, my code is an example to show you how to use `onchange` event to autosubmit the form when the user selects files, `it's the answer to your question`. Now, you can remove the "upload.php", then paste your code in my code. It will work. Anyway, you should not mix the HTML code with the PHP code that executes the action, because when the page refreshes the action is re-executed.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Okay thank you very much - have gotten this to work now :)